# How to create crunchydata postgres cluster using CRD on Terraform?

Tags: postgresql, terraform

I created K8S cluster using Terraform and I also created CRD for Crunchydata Postgres Operator

I obtained CRD for Postgres cluster creation from this [link](https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/latest/custom-resources/)

Terraform script looks like below (tailored output)

```
resource "kubectl_manifest" "pgocluster" {
  yaml_body = <<YAML
apiVersion: crunchydata.com/v1
kind: Pgcluster
metadata:
  annotations:
    current-primary: ${var.pgo_cluster_name}
  labels:
    crunchy-pgha-scope: ${var.pgo_cluster_name}
    deployment-name: ${var.pgo_cluster_name}
    name: ${var.pgo_cluster_name}
    pg-cluster: ${var.pgo_cluster_name}
    pgo-version: 4.6.2
    pgouser: admin
  name: ${var.pgo_cluster_name}
  namespace: ${var.cluster_namespace}
YAML
}
```

But when I execute 'terraform apply' it errored as

```
Error: pgo/UserGrp failed to create kubernetes rest client for update of resource: resource [crunchydata.com/v1/Pgcluster] isn't valid for cluster, check the APIVersion and Kind fields are valid
```

However, according to the official link mentioned above following should work

```
apiVersion: crunchydata.com/v1
kind: Pgcluster
```

I am not sure whether it's issue with Terraform or link was not updated correctly

Kindly let me know what should be changed / done to fix this issue as I am stuck with this issue

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured out the issue and the issue was `pgo_cluster_name` was not given in lowercase

I was able to get the following error only when I executed the target individually ie `terraform  apply --target=<target_name>`

```
Error: pgo/UserGrp failed to run apply: error when creating "/tmp/773985147kubectl_manifest.yaml": Pgcluster.crunchydata.com "UserGrp" is invalid: metadata.name: Invalid value: "UserGrp": a lowercase RFC 1123 subdomain must consist of lower case alphanumeric characters, '-' or '.', and must start and end with an alphanumeric character (e.g. 'example.com', regex used for validation is '[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?(\.[a-z0-9]([-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?)*')
```

I set `pgo_cluster_name=UsrGrp` instead of `pgo_cluster_name=usrgrp`